# View PDF through java App

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, desktop-application

I want to know how I can view a PDF through a Java App.
I am trying to create a application to view PDF using NetBeans 6.8

There are few pdf reader libraries such as iText pdfBox. But they didn't help me

Please help me! any help is appreciate

Thank You!

Comment: You need to actively show it in your Java application, or you just need to show it?  If it is the latter, you can ask the operating system to show a file you point to from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [PDF renderer](https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 2):

There is also an Open Source PDF viewer plugin for NetBeans here http://www.jpedal.org/support_siNetBeans.php