# Is it possible to view pdf file through the gui in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View PDF through java App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874354/view-pdf-through-java-app)

I just want to know, is it possible to view pdf file in java? and what is the suitable componenet to view the pdf file through it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of Open Source and commerical libraries to view PDFs including BFO, PDF-Renderer, JPedal, Multivalent, Qoppa, Crionics.